# I am getting error -**The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Object** , how do solve this error?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\eclipse-workspace\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
    
List links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(" Total number of links exist on page"+links.size());

int internal_count=0;
int external_count=0;

for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++) {

    String str1 =links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
    boolean b = str1.startsWith("https://www.flipkart");

    if(b) {
        System.out.println("Internal Link"+str1);
        internal_count++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("External Link"+str1);
        external_count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `List links` to `List<WebElement> links`

Comment: Your List `link` has no generics defined, so Java consider its elements as `Object`. When you do `links.get(i)` you receive an `Object` and there is no method `getAttribute()` in this class. See Fenio's comment to correct it.

Comment: thanku Fenio and vincrichaud, i changed the code to List<WebElement> links  but running time I'm getting exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @QBrute changing to List<WebElement> solved the error but when I run the code it is throwing some exception

Comment: @userCoding have a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @vincrichaud yes will look into it...thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
List links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

should be

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Rest your code looks fine.

**Code:**

```
@Test
public void testSO() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(" Total number of links exist on page" +links.size());

    int internal_count=0;
    int external_count=0;

    for (WebElement ele : links) {
        try {
            if(ele.getAttribute("href").startsWith("https://www.flipkart")) {
                System.out.println("Internal Link" +ele.getAttribute("href"));
                internal_count++;
            }
            else {
            System.out.println("External Link" +ele.getAttribute("href"));
            external_count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

```
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/beardo-hair-thickening-hemp-miracle-oil-100-ml-non-sticky-light-styling-oil-men-pleasant-fragrance-light-daily-strengthening-made-seeds/p/itm093a5e74cee0a?pid=HOLG7ZY3CZ9NZSCH&otracker=hp_bannerads_4_2.bannerAdCard.BANNERADS_Beardo_ZVU5VCL4BXV7
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/big-bachat-dhamaal-sale-store?otracker=hp_bannerads_1_2.bannerAdCard.BANNERADS_x_4FZ1XM53CE6H
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mobile-bonanza-november21-82d23e23e-store?param=344&otracker=hp_bannerads_2_2.bannerAdCard.BANNERADS_Cat-Mob-HPW-bonanza_RDICDI1L00IW
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/tyy/4io/~cs-estydyrnah/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&collection-tab-name=POCO+C31&param=3764&sort=price_asc&otracker=hp_bannerads_3_2.bannerAdCard.BANNERADS_Cat-mob-HPW-POCO-C31_23RLED5KYVP9
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/beardo-hair-thickening-hemp-miracle-oil-100-ml-non-sticky-light-styling-oil-men-pleasant-fragrance-light-daily-strengthening-made-seeds/p/itm093a5e74cee0a?pid=HOLG7ZY3CZ9NZSCH&otracker=hp_bannerads_4_2.bannerAdCard.BANNERADS_Beardo_ZVU5VCL4BXV7
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/big-bachat-dhamaal-sale-store?otracker=hp_bannerads_1_2.bannerAdCard.BANNERADS_x_4FZ1XM53CE6H
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/bank-terms-and-conditions-store
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/top-offers?screen=dynamic&pk=themeViews%3DEvents-Topoffers%3ADeal-card~widgetType%3DdealCard~contentType%3Dneo&wid=4.dealCard.OMU_4&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_wc_view-all_4
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/musical-instruments/keys-synthesizers/musical-keyboards/pr?sid=ypu%2Cnvg%2Cxqg&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_82c87020-80c1-4789-9bfb-069611120363_1_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.OOB97OQG0WN4&otracker1=hp_rich_navigation_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_NA_NAV_EXPANDABLE_navigationCard_cc_10_L2_view-all&cid=OOB97OQG0WN4&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DCASIO&hpid=RwATOSxQ1qqKCH4NsXvc5qp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.E08CO5ZI3RWQ&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_1_4.dealCard.OMU_E08CO5ZI3RWQ_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_1_NA_view-all_4&cid=E08CO5ZI3RWQ
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/musical-instruments/keys-synthesizers/musical-keyboards/pr?sid=ypu%2Cnvg%2Cxqg&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D30%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D40%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D20%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.MA7OV7VPYOAB&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_2_4.dealCard.OMU_MA7OV7VPYOAB_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_2_NA_view-all_4&cid=MA7OV7VPYOAB
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/musical-instruments/~cs-wg8z12xdtk/pr?sid=ypu&collection-tab-name=Top%20100%20Musical%20Instruments%20&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.7DWQQRP3RR4F&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_3_4.dealCard.OMU_7DWQQRP3RR4F_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_3_NA_view-all_4&cid=7DWQQRP3RR4F
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/furniture/furniture-accessories/home-temple/~cs-g6oe1x4pkp/pr?sid=wwe%2Cq7b%2C9zz&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D1000&hpid=LAjFz_9NEAXsj-og4Wh6oqp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.3KG9W7QD6EGI&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_4_4.dealCard.OMU_3KG9W7QD6EGI_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_4_NA_view-all_4&cid=3KG9W7QD6EGI
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/water-purifiers/~cs-czjgpiv7tz/pr?sid=j9e%2Cabm%2Ci45&p%5B%5D=facets.fulfilled_by%255B%255D%3DFlipkart%2BAssured&sort=popularity&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3D4999&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3DMax&p%5B%5D=facets.type%255B%255D%3DElectrical%2B%2526%2BStorage&hpid=QuztcqFM-5hkwIeW5VSAXKp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.FCGOUHJTNPZT&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_5_4.dealCard.OMU_FCGOUHJTNPZT_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_5_NA_view-all_4&cid=FCGOUHJTNPZT
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/beauty-and-grooming/~cs-enwwn6uk96/pr?sid=g9b&collection-tab-name=Cara%20Mia%20Grooming&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.E09D87ZFEODR&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_6_4.dealCard.OMU_E09D87ZFEODR_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_6_NA_view-all_4&cid=E09D87ZFEODR
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/furniture/cabinets/kitchen-cabinets/~cs-g6oe1x4pkp/pr?sid=wwe%2C6by%2C9dn&sort=popularity&hpid=W2rAJ_wo8Z7M-8NyPRaGlqp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.NSRZGI8QGNLN&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_7_4.dealCard.OMU_NSRZGI8QGNLN_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_7_NA_view-all_4&cid=NSRZGI8QGNLN
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/musical-instruments/studiostage-equipment-accessories/microphone/pr?sid=ypu%2Calc%2C3d4&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D30%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_e627ea1b-d9b1-4edd-aa1d-b83b01ff8061_2_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.KZXMK6CTEATF&cid=KZXMK6CTEATF&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D40%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D50%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D60%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&p%5B%5D=facets.fulfilled_by%255B%255D%3DFlipkart%2BAssured&hpid=QEJRKfD47pPwmcs_kafF5ap7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_4.XYO7BWXT7RSW&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Top%2BOffers_8_4.dealCard.OMU_XYO7BWXT7RSW_4&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Top%2BOffers_NA_dealCard_cc_8_NA_view-all_4&cid=XYO7BWXT7RSW
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/beauty-and-grooming/pr?sid=g9b&p%5B%5D=facets.fulfilled_by%255B%255D%3DFlipkart%2BAssured&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_633a116c-4415-41ab-9491-8a20111baf68_1_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.NJKL2WGZ9KLB&otracker1=hp_rich_navigation_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_NA_NAV_EXPANDABLE_navigationCard_cc_1_L2_view-all&cid=NJKL2WGZ9KLB&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DHIMALAYA&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D30%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&nnc=H4NAXEAJJRPA_AD&otracker=hp_rhs_announcement_1_5.rhsAnnouncement.RHS_ANNOUNCEMENT_H4NAXEAJJRPA
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/todays-fashion-deals?screen=dynamic&pk=themeViews%3DLS-Big-Bachat-Topdeals%3ADD-HP~widgetType%3DdealCard~contentType%3Dneo&wid=7.dealCard.OMU_6&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_wc_view-all_6
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/winter-wear/pr?sid=clo%2Cqvw&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DGirls&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DBoys&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DBoys%2B%2526%2BGirls&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DBaby%2BBoys&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DBaby%2BGirls&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DBaby%2BBoys%2B%2526%2BBaby%2BGirls&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D499&parm=2345&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.78WV1FRYA60C&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_1_7.dealCard.OMU_78WV1FRYA60C_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_1_NA_view-all_6&cid=78WV1FRYA60C
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/~cs-tzjb72e1aj/pr?sid=clo&collection-tab-name=Women+Ethnic+Collection&sort=popularity&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3D149&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D799&hpid=zbZjjUbBXI0EDiDgrAjeVKp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.EYSDGGNPWUTH&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_2_7.dealCard.OMU_EYSDGGNPWUTH_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_2_NA_view-all_6&cid=EYSDGGNPWUTH
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/watches/wrist-watches/pr?sid=r18%2Cf13&param=123&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3D99&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3DMax&hpid=WdeGhtwd13Uj2HN5GqNkCKp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.RKWUSVMR227W&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_3_7.dealCard.OMU_RKWUSVMR227W_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_3_NA_view-all_6&cid=RKWUSVMR227W
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/backpacks/~cs-yqpnjob9z8/pr?sid=reh%2C4d7%2Cak9&p%5B%5D=facets.fulfilled_by%255B%255D%3DFlipkart%2BAssured&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3D500&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D799&hpid=VnFtb8NWuX1GpQJ-FmwgU6p7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.IR402XXGLDXX&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_4_7.dealCard.OMU_IR402XXGLDXX_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_4_NA_view-all_6&cid=IR402XXGLDXX
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/pr?sid=osp%2Ccil&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3D199&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D1000&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DUnited%2BColors%2Bof%2BBenetton&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DBond%2BStreet%2BBy%2BRed%2BTape&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DBata&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DBata%2BLeisure&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DADIDAS%2BNEO&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRED%2BCHIEF&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DHUSH%2BPUPPIES&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DPeter%2BEngland%2BPE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DADIDAS%2BORIGINALS&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DConverse&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DV%2BDot%2BVan%2BHeusen&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSole%2BThreads&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DWildcraft&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSuperdry&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DREEBOK%2BCLASSICS&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DWROGN&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DJACK%2B%2526%2BJONES&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DALDO&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DFRANCO%2BLEONE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DAllen%2BSolly&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSpykar&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DGliders%2Bby%2BLiberty&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DFsports&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DBen%2BSherman&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DA-HA%2BBy%2BLiberty&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DLakhani&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DAqualite&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DParagon&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DKhadim%2527s&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DFrench%2BConnection&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRoadster&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DMast%2B%2526%2BHarbour&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DKook%2BN%2BKeech&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3Dether&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DLakhani%2BVardaan&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DCARLTON%2BLONDON&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DAsics%2BTIGER&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DAttilio&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DPROVOGUE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DLEE%2BCOOPER&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DWOODLAND&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DVANS&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DLEVI%2527S&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DU.S.%2BPOLO%2BASSN.&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRED%2BTAPE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DCROCS&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSPARX&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DCLARKS&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DINDIGO%2BNATION&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DMETRONAUT&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DNORTH%2BSTAR&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSAN%2BFRISSCO&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DARROW&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DFLYING%2BMACHINE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DRUOSH&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DPAVERS%2BENGLAND&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DDIESEL&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DCALL%2BIT%2BSPRING&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DVAN%2BHEUSEN&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DDUCATI&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DMERRELL&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DTOMMY%2BHILFIGER&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DPARK%2BAVENUE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DALBERTO%2BTORRESI&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DAEROPOSTALE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DCOOLERS%2BBY%2BLIBERTY&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DDUKE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DLIBERTY&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DACTION&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DPETER%2BENGLAND&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DLakhani%2Btouch&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DMUFTI&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DPEOPLE&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DMOCHI&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DWOODS&sort=popularity&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.DJCJ9195EBUO&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_5_7.dealCard.OMU_DJCJ9195EBUO_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_5_NA_view-all_6&cid=DJCJ9195EBUO
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/~cs-yzilopt3p8/pr?sid=clo&collection-tab-name=Tops%2C+T-Shirts%2C+Dresses...&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3D149&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D1000&hpid=TWo_EwOlsYzw1DDFcKOQaKp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.TN1CG1EY4CMN&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_6_7.dealCard.OMU_TN1CG1EY4CMN_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_6_NA_view-all_6&cid=TN1CG1EY4CMN
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/jewellery/artificial-jewellery/pr?sid=mcr%2C96v&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D699&p%5B%5D=facets.collection%255B%255D%3DEthnic&hpid=VKH3yT84bVxY1S5A91lt46p7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.BUOZUKQAL36D&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_7_7.dealCard.OMU_BUOZUKQAL36D_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_7_NA_view-all_6&cid=BUOZUKQAL36D
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/sunglasses/pr?sid=26x&marketplace=FLIPKART&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DWomen&sort=popularity&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DGirls&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3D99&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D999&hpid=sBoRpaNyOuh339dVXUhheqp7_Hsxr70nj65vMAAFKlc=&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_3b6d0781-2ea7-4fbd-bf4f-8c5323192577_7.JVBKMIXVB2XT&ppt=None&ppn=None&ssid=u5peumxc340000001637319966144&otracker=hp_omu_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_8_7.dealCard.OMU_JVBKMIXVB2XT_6&otracker1=hp_omu_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Today%2527s%2BFashion%2BDeals_NA_dealCard_cc_8_NA_view-all_6&cid=JVBKMIXVB2XT
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/brands
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-13-pink-128-gb/p/itm6e30c6ee045d2?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-13-pro-graphite-512-gb/p/itm5c4ef35fbe69f?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-13-pro-max-sierra-blue-128-gb/p/itm5ede69d71530a?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-13-mini-starlight-128-gb/p/itmcb65606f21fd3?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/tv-and-appliances-big-billion-days-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/flipkart-pay-later-emi-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/big-billion-days-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/motor-insurance-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/flipkartquick-hyperlocal-campaign-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/ed-a-mamma~brand/pr?sid=clo&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/books-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/flipkart-electronics-sale-tv-and-appliances-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/grand-kitchen-sale-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/all-auto-accessories-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/sunglasses/streak-specsmakers~brand/pr?sid=26x&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/q/gold-coins?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/bgm-big-billion-days-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/home-bbd-intriuge-dhamaka-sale-pn-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/plus?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/supercoin?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/covid-insurance-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/helpcentre?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/helpcentre/trackOrder/i/2?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/helpcentre/manageOrder/i/3?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/helpcentre/returnOrder/i/4?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/the-gift-card-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/q/sarees?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/flipkart-axis-bank-credit-card-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/flipkart-pay-later-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/jewellery/pr?sid=mcr&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/watches/pr?sid=r18&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/jewellery/~gold-coins/pr?sid=mcr&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mangalsutra/pr?sid=mcr,96v,t4i,0f4&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/sunglasses/pr?sid=26x&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/sunglasses/mi~brand/pr?sid=26x&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/backpacks/pr?sid=reh%2C4d7%2Cak9&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/sunglasses/ray-ban~brand/pr?sid=26x&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-12-white-64-gb/p/itm8b88bdc03cd79?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-12-pro-graphite-512-gb/p/itmdf0ffb4f2150f?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-12-blue-128-gb/p/itm02853ae92e90a?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/vivo-y91i-fusion-black-32-gb/p/itmff6vsadyrbauf?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/vivo-y11-mineral-blue-32-gb/p/itmb764fb6d6ef60?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/vivo-y15-aqua-blue-64-gb/p/itmfgadf77s87w8x?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/vivo-y50-pearl-white-128-gb/p/itmd0dcc06ffbe06?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/vivo-y12-burgundy-red-64-gb/p/itmfhyjvucp5mueg?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/oppo-reno2-f-lake-green-256-gb/p/itm8413e7eb0b195?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/oppo-a12-blue-32-gb/p/itmfc859cdf39e01?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/oppo-f15-blazing-blue-128-gb/p/itm56d35565691ea?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/oppo-a31-fantasy-white-64-gb/p/itm82e19f459118a?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-a71-prism-crush-blue-128-gb/p/itmb719fd01880e3?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-a51-prism-crush-blue-128-gb/p/itme8079f0fedb33?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-a31-prism-crush-white-128-gb/p/itma110137399bdc?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/realme-x2-pearl-green-64-gb/p/itm75023903eb431?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/realme-5-crystal-purple-32-gb/p/itmfj9twbwfznhyk?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/infinix-hot-8-quetzal-cyan-64-gb/p/itm176568dde7f63?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-11-white-64-gb/p/itm2644c3764fc54?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-11-pro-space-grey-64-gb/p/itm7e24c1c560208?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-11-pro-max-gold-64-gb/p/itm6ef18218efdf6?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mobile-phone-offers-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-x-space-gray-64-gb/p/itmexrgv6hctyrav?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-8-silver-64-gb/p/itmexrgvsw7vedwq?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-7-black-32-gb/p/itmen6daftcqwzeg?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6-space-grey-32-gb/p/itmetmh3hfhnxtcj?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/redmi-5a-gold-16-gb/p/itmfy6cg6a5m7mwh?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/4g-mobile-phones-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/nokia-mobile-phones-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/samsung-mobile-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/apple~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/oppo-mobile-phones-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/vivo-mobile-phones-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/gopro-hero-sports-action-camera/p/itmf3s4abpfgawhc?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/cameras/nikon~brand/pr?sid=jek,p31&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/cameras/canon~brand/pr?sid=jek,p31&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/q/sony-cameras?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/q/canon-dslr-cameras?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/cameras/dslr-mirrorless/nikon~brand/pr?sid=jek,p31,trv&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/microsoft-surface-go-pentium-gold-4-gb-64-gb-emmc-storage-windows-10-home-s-mode-1824-2-1-laptop/p/itmfb6pyegb9vgck?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/microsoft-surface-go-pentium-gold-8-gb-128-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-s-mode-1824-2-1-laptop/p/itmfb6pyjzy9y8n4?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops/apple~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops/acer~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops/lenovo~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops/dell~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops/asus~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops/hp~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/gaming/gaming-laptops/pr?sid=4rr,tz1&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~2-in-1-laptops/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/computers/~business-laptops/pr?sid=6bo&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/tv-and-appliances-big-billion-days-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/televisions/motorola~brand/pr?sid=ckf,czl&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/q/redmi-smart-tvs?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/televisions/oneplus~brand/pr?sid=ckf,czl&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/launching-realme-sled-4k-smart-tv-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mi-led-smart-tv-4x-108-cm-43/p/itmab87244d2fead?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mi-led-smart-tv-4a-100-cm-40/p/itmaaa9224388773?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mi-led-smart-tv-4x-163-9-cm-65/p/itm4b78549a6a25e?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/samsung-7-in-1-80cm-32-inch-hd-ready-led-smart-tv/p/itmfga98hypx8wzc?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/televisions/lg~brand/pr?sid=ckf,czl&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/television-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/televisions/sony~brand/pr?sid=ckf,czl&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/televisions/samsung~brand/pr?sid=ckf,czl&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/mi-led-smart-tv-4a-pro-123-2-cm-49/p/itmfcp72rrahu6vf?pid=TVSFCP72GZYESDHF&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/android-tv-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/iffalcon-by-tcl-smart-tvs-launch-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/televisions/mi~brand/pr?sid=ckf,czl&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/tv-and-appliances-big-billion-days-store?otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/washing-machines/pr?sid=j9e,abm,8qx&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/refrigerators/pr?sid=j9e,abm,hzg&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/air-conditioners/pr?sid=j9e,abm,c54&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/air-fryers/pr?sid=j9e,m38,j1e&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/appliance-parts-accessories/pr?sid=j9e,m38,vli&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/bread-makers/pr?sid=j9e,m38,y3d&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/cake-maker/pr?sid=j9e,m38,z9o&otracker=undefined_footer_footer
```

Comment: I have changed my code and used the for loop you have given above. When I run the code it is throwing an exception:                                                                                                                                                   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getAttribute(String)" is null
 at selenium.InternalExternalLinks.main(InternalExternalLinks.java:32)

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getAttribute(String)" is null
 at selenium.InternalExternalLinks.main(InternalExternalLinks.java:32)

Comment: Use this loop for debugging purpose `for (WebElement ele : links) {
   System.out.println("Attributes" +ele.getAttribute("href"));}` and see if it is printing anything or not.

Comment: Ya this loop works fine it is printing all the links.

Comment: okay, this is also for debugging, you can use the first loop from the answer and can have this if condition `if(ele.getAttribute("href").contains("https://www.flipkart"))`

Comment: it is throwing this exception-   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because the return value of "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getAttribute(String)" is null
 at selenium.InternalExternalLinks.main(InternalExternalLinks.java:32)

Comment: that's not the ideal behavior, can you share HTML ? or link to the page ?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: You have to provide the page url here with me..

Comment: i didn't get...page url?  i am writing the code in eclipse

Comment: driver.get(""), in this line what do you have ?

Comment: [link](https://www.flipkart.com)

Comment: Total number of links exist on page449
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/plus
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/account/login?ret=/
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/viewcart?otracker=Cart_Icon_Click
Internal Linkhttps://www.flipkart.com/offers-store?otracker=nmenu_offer-zone&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_0ee24d96-a909-43c0-8ef5-293e47021540_1_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.G6ZC4RAJ9OHU&otracker=hp_rich_navigation_1_1.navigationCard.RICH_NAVIGATION_Top%2BOffers_G6ZC4RAJ9OHU&otracker1=hp_rich_navigation_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_NA_NAV_EXPANDABLE_navi

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: i  got partial output.......internal and external links are showing but in between NullPointer Exception ...the earlier one is  also showing

Answer (score 0):

As *@vincrichaud* correctly pointed out in the comment, as you declared the list `links` it had no generics defined, so Java consider its elements type as `Object`. Moving forward, when you do:

```
links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
```

The objects are iterated which have no method as `getAttribute()`. Hence you see the error:

```
The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Object
```

---

### Solution

While declaring the list include the generics type as [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) as follows:

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Comment: Thankyou @DebanjanB i changed the code but im getting expection when i run the code

Comment: What exception are you facing? Can you update the question with the exception details?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because the return value of "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getAttribute(String)" is null
 at selenium.InternalExternalLinks.main(InternalExternalLinks.java:35)`

Comment: _`NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)"`_ sounds to be a different error all together, where as your main question was _`The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Object`_ Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: changed the code a bit. I put `List<WebElement>` then used                                    
          `for (WebElement ele : links) 
     {
      if(ele.getAttribute("href").contains("https://www.flipkart.com"))
      {  
       System.out.println("Internal Link: " +ele.getAttribute("href"));
       internal_count++;
      }
      else 
      {
      
       System.out.println("External Link: " +ele.getAttribute("href"));
       external_count++;
      
      }
    }`